# Can I lock my PC(Win10 OS) and still run audio in my DAW and playback softwares?

Tags: display, lock, playback

Is it possible to lock the PC without it quitting or muting 
my Digital Audio Workstation(FL Studio 12) and audio playback? I've tried it several times... but the audio just kept on muting. It's very crucial for me since I'd like to keep my PC secured when going for a quick break without ruining the mix when mixing a live show. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably software dependent, since I know that some audio playback continues while locked, while other players halt playback..

I think that FL Studio has a setting to disable playback when minimized: "Auto close device" in the audio options.

You also want to ensure sleep and hibernate are disabled.

Comment: OK, Yurik. Thanks, but how will I disable sleep and hibernate as you mentioned in the last paragraph?

Comment: That would be in the power settings options (control panel). Some laptops have a physical switch where if you close the lid they sleep also.

Comment: Sorry... I realised I misspelt your name the first time ... I already set my laptop to do nothing when I close the lid. My concern is about it not cutting any processes when I actually lock it, so as for me to go for a break. I want to prevent it from being tampered it while it's locked and still have my DAW running in the background... Yorik, hope you get me?